# Ubuntu Python3 double printing output

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

Am I losing my mind?

```
import json
import websockets
print("Testing")
print("blah")
```

Results in:

```
tony@ubuntu:~/Documents/google_maps$ python3 websockets.py 
Testing
blah
Testing
blah
```

If I remove the import for websockets, the lines are only printed once.  Anyone know why this is happening?

--UPDATE--

It appears I am dumb, so I'll leave this up in case anyone else is as foolish as I...

Comment: you have called your script the same name as the module. so when your script runs, it will try to import websockets which is the name of your script I.E it runs it again. Lesson is dont call your scripts the same name as modules you want to use

Comment: Ahh yes, of course, thanks for the info haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writting my comment as an answer for completeness to the question.

You have called your script websockets.py. When you do the import your script will import its self. I.E you script will first call its self, which will result in the first two prints. Once its called its self it will then run the two prints which will result in 4 prints being executed.